# How can I access redux store outside a component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I've a API file and a `token` in redux store. I've tried with `getState()` but the token will stored after a user signs in so it's giving me error of undefined. How do I solve this problem?

```
const token = store.getState().verification.token;
```

```
import axios from "axios";

const ApiInstance = axios.create({

});

// console.log(process.env);


ApiInstance.defaults.headers.post["content-type"] = "application/json";
ApiInstance.defaults.headers.get["Accept"] = "application/json";
ApiInstance.defaults.headers.get["Authorization"] =
  `Bearer ${token}`;

export default ApiInstance;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use Axios Interceptor! :)

You shouldn't use `.defaults` for authorization in most cases anyway because ideally your token will expire after some time period.  A better approach would be to use an axios interceptor.

Bascially axios lets you define a function that will run EVERY time an HTTP request is made. In that function you can call `store.getState()` and then append the token to the request headers.

For example, you could use the following:

```
ApiInstance.interceptors.request.use(req => {
  let myToken = store.getState().verification.token;
  req.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${myToken}`;
  return req;
});
```